# Why are things changing sizes in Disney's Epic Mickey?

Tags: disney, epic-mickey

There is a thing I don't understand in this game (and in its Graphic Novel): how things who fall in Wasteland change size. Because basically, Wasteland is only a micro-world created by Yensid with his magic brush, set on his working table. Or is it ? It is not clarified if the "Wasteland 3D Map" we see during the opening is really *Wasteland itself* or a gate who allows the people who jump in it to arrive in Wasteland. In any case, when Mickey fall in the "map" at the beginning of the story, he changes size and is "on scale" with the Micro-world he's in. But… the Thinner Bottle that he clumsily let falling from Yensid's drawing board into the Magical Map keeps the size it had with regard to the original map, and so seems gigantic in Wasteland. Why ? Are characters the only ones who change sizes, and not the objects ? But so why weren't Mickey's clothes giant too ?